# Can't change Perforce host

Tags: perforce, host

Some time ago I seemed to have locked in my P4 host and can't change it.

I've tried

```
set p4host=my_host
```

but it doesn't seem to clear it out or change it. Command line `p4 info` returns the old host name. I'm unsure how I got it this way -- possibly by setting it system wide, but now I'm unsure how to revert it. I'm in a directory that does not have a p4config.txt file and is empty.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
p4 set P4HOST
```

to see where your P4HOST value is coming from.  Different ways of setting it (P4CONFIG, system environment, registry, P4ENV) have different levels of precedence.

Unfortunately I don't know what platform you're on so I can't give any hints about likely places to look, but hopefully whatever `p4 set` tells you will put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question to Win 10. I found that a lot of my old "p4config.txt" files were taking precedence in the p4 environment variables. I deleted all of them, however I'm still getting it set to something old. I tried creating a new workspace (and for some reason the "host" field in the advanced options of the workspace was set to an old host I don't want to use). Still possibly getting set somewhere else?

Comment: What does the command I suggested running (`p4 set P4HOST`) tell you?

Comment: It looks like I had Windows "set" and P4's environment "set" to different things. I went and cleared all those out with "set p4 p4host=" and "set p4host=" and things seem to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was unable to switch or access my workspace as hostname was changed. I just followed the following steps:

1. Right-click 'Edit workspace'.
2. Go to the 'Advanced' tab.
3. Change the hostname and hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

use export P4HOST=""

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.