# git p4 client mismatch while migrating workspace

Tags: git, perforce

I'm new to Perforce's p4 CLI but use Perforce Helix Cloud regularly. I'm trying to migrate a Perforce workspace into git using git-p4 with the following command:

`git-p4 clone //path/to/perforce/workspace`

The migration fails with the following error:

`p4 returned an error: //path/to/perforce/workspace - must refer to client 'LAPTOP-NAME'.`

Where `LAPTOP-NAME` is the name of my laptop. I've tried clearing out and updating the `P4HOST` name for the workspace with both Helix Visual Client and the P4 command `p4 set P4HOST=LAPTOP-NAME` (as in [Can't change Perforce host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266408/cant-change-perforce-host)), but it has no effect.

Since this is also my first time using p4, perhaps some additional setup is necessary?

I have also tried setting my p4 configuration:

```
p4 set P4PORT=server.example.com:1666
p4 set P4USER=username
p4 set P4PASSWD=password123
p4 set P4CLIENT=client-dev
```

Trying to perform the migration after setting the configuration no longer throws the client error, but throws the error

```
User <username> does not exist
```

Although the username is definitely accurate.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What kind of path is `//path/to/perforce/workspace`?  You've formatted it like a depot path, but the error indicates that it's not one.

Comment: @Samwise It is placeholder for a depot path taken straight from Perforce Helix Cloud. Are there any other reasons this error could be occurring? Is it possible that I need additional permissions for CLI access as opposed to Helix Cloud access to the depot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you haven't specified a valid P4USER.

Comment: It's impossible to double-check for typos when all the info is obfuscated, but start with running "p4 info" from the CLI -- does it look like you're connected to the right server?  Is the username exactly what you expect?  (It might be case-sensitive depending on server settings!)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Samwise! I got this to work now. This turned out to be a simple case of updating the P4CLIENT name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work now. This turned out to be a simple case of updating the P4CLIENT name. The git-p4 CLI needed this updated in the p4 CLI.